# Does "lower and higher brackets" work?

Tags: meaning-in-context

As you can see, there are two lower income brackets and only one higher bracket. Is it correct to call these three brackets "lower and higher brackets"? What I am worried about is that the "brackets" in "lower and higher brackets" is plural. Does it sound like there are more than one higher bracket?

> In all three years, significantly fewer households were in the
> $50,000–$74,999 and $75,000–$99,999 income brackets than **lower and
> higher brackets**. (I wrote it)

Edit:
I now have new concerns after reading the comment. Does the sentence above sound like I'm comparing the **combined total** of households in the $50,000–$74,999 and $75,000–$99,999  brackets to the **combined total** of households in the other three brackets. Should I use "or" instead of "and"?

> In all three years, significantly fewer households were in the
> $50,000–$74,999 **or** the $75,000–$99,999 income brackets than the higher **or** lower brackets.

[image]

Comment: You could sidestep your quandary by rephrasing your sentence: *In all three years, significantly less than half the households were in the $50,000–$74,999 and $75,000–$99,999 income brackets*, or even *In all three years, significantly fewer households had income between $50,000 and $99,999*.

Comment: Thank you, @PaulTanenbaum. Your second sentence made my realize that I might have combined brackets. I want to talk about bracket individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works fine. "lower and higher brackets" implies more than one bracket in total. There is no implication that there are more than one higher and more than one lower bracket.

I would also put "the" before the phrase. I know that using or not using articles can be tricky. There are many questions on here about this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have new concerns so I updated my question. Could you also explain the combined total part?

Comment: This could be open to the interpretation you are worried about. "fewer households were in EITHER the $50,000–$74,999 OR THE $75,000–$99,999 income brackets than the lower and higher brackets" removes any ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks again. Does "the lower **and** higher brackets" also sound like the combined total of households in these brackets? Would it be better to use "or"? Fewer households were in EITHER the $50,000–$74,999 OR THE $75,000–$99,999 income brackets than the lower **OR** higher brackets". Is "either" absolutely necessary? Can I not use it? Fewer households were in the $50,000–$74,999 **OR** $75,000–$99,999 income brackets than the lower **OR** higher brackets"

Comment: Having added the OR earlier it might be better to use it later as you suggest. "either" could be omitted but I would keep it for clarity in written English, and especially something technical like this where precision matters more than brevity.

Comment: Thanks again. Does "either" work with "higher or lower brackets"? Fewer households were in either the $50,000–$74,999 or the $75,000–$99,999 income brackets than **either** the lower or the higher brackets"?

Comment: Yes it does work. Not necessary but  ok. I probably wouldn't usually but in technical or academic writing it may avoid any possible ambiguity. Note that the definite article before the second option helps with this anyway.